# How can i create a list of elements?

Tags: c#, animation, xna

i'm making a fighting game with a lot of hitsparks but i don't know ho to make a list of elements to draw multiple hitspark (by now, there can be only one hitspark in the screen). I know a List thing exists but i really don't know how to use it.
Here is how i handle hitspark by now.

```
    AnimationElement HitElement;
    private Preparationanimation Hit4;

 public override void  LoadContent()
 {
        HitElement = new AnimationElement();
        Hit4 = new Preparationanimation(SpriteSheetElements1, new Color(255, 255, 255, 128), 1f, false)
 }

 if (IntersectPixels(Player1.HitboxAtt, Player1.playerTextureData, Player2.Hitbox, Player2.playerTextureData))
 {
        HitElement.PlayAnimation(Hit4, content);
 }

 public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
 {
         HitElement.Draw(spriteBatch, gameTime, positionElement, false, true);
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<AnimationElement> HitElements;
private Preparationanimation Hit4;

 public override void LoadContent()
 {
        HitElements = new List<AnimationElement>();
        Hit4 = new Preparationanimation(SpriteSheetElements1, new Color(255, 255, 255, 128), 1f, false)
 }

 if (IntersectPixels(Player1.HitboxAtt, Player1.playerTextureData, Player2.Hitbox, Player2.playerTextureData))
 {
     foreach (AnimationElement a in HitElements)
     {
       a.PlayAnimation(Hit4, content);
     }
 }

 public override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
 {
     foreach (AnimationElement a in HitElements)
     {
         a.Draw(spriteBatch, gameTime, positionElement, false, true);
     }

 }
```

You need a List for multiple objects. You can add using HitElements.Add. Also why is there an If statement in the middle of your code?

More information can be found [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/list).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and this link. The if statement was to show when the Hitspark is created.

Comment: I tried it. Worked perfectly. There is a bug now where the first Hitspark dra in a strange color but one point for you cyral

Comment: I got it, it is because i need to erase the elements. They kept adding each other.

Comment: Ah No problem. Try Remove Or RemoveAt.